Why are characters like "ã" appearing encoded in UTF-8 in Git and how to fix it?
I'm using Git to version my code, but I noticed that some commits have the author names encoded in UTF-8 in a strange way. For example, the author name "João" appears like this when I .patch the commit via the browser:
From: =?UTF-8?q?Jo=C3=A3o?= <joop011122@gmail.com>

How can I fix this and make author names appear correctly, without this encoding, when making commits in Git?

That's not exactly "appearing encoded in UTF-8" – author names in Git have always been encoded in UTF-8, that's what allows them to be displayed correctly in the first place. What you're seeing is really the opposite, a re-encoding of UTF-8 into something else (q is the actual encoding indication and stands for Quoted-Printable) so that it may pass through non-UTF-8-capable systems.

Your commit is still encoded in UTF-8.  But the patch format that you
are using there uses an encoding [1] for email headers.  The patch
format is geared towards sending patches via email.  Email headers
should not contain non-ASCII text.  The commit author is put in the
From header, hence Git has to encode the value if it has a non-ASCII
value like “ã” (Latin small letter a with tilde).
In summary there is nothing wrong with the commit message itself.  It’s
still in UTF-8.  But GitHub (see tag) chose to use the patch format with
this header encoding for displaying the commit. [2]
Notes

Q-encoding, described in RFC 2047
Email header encoding can be turned off with git format-patch --no-encode-email-headers

